# Is there any keyboard shortcut for Gradle Sync Now in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

[image]

Anyone know if there is any short key for App Level Gradle Syncing in Android Studio?

Comment: It's a great question. Increases productivity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can configure the shortcut from **Preferences** -> **Keymap** as shown in below screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Also you can press Alt + Enter, then pop up will appear with option to sync.
Just hit enter again and it will sync.

I know is not like real shortcut, because you need to hit enter twice.
But still faster than using mouse.

[What you can see after press Alt + Enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyJbT.png)